# C# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am getting the error in the title when I run this code during the `Add` method. The `Add` method should add the gameobject to a list called queue.
`GameObject` is a class.
`GameManager` is a class as well.
`queue` is a list.

I think this is the only code relevant.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        GameObject obj1 = new GameObject();
        GameManager manager1 = new GameManager();
        obj1.name = "First";
        manager1.Add(obj1);
        manager1.Process();
    }

    public void Add(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        gameObject.initialize = true;
        queue.Add(gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever initialize the list? Also, there is a `Queue` that may be more appropriate than a `List`.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Did you debug it and find what is null?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **initializing the field "queue"**:

- It's probably never initialized, hence the `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object    error` error, which by the structure of the `Add` method is likely to correspond to `queue`.
- Also - **I would consider renaming queue** to a meaningful name, since it is currently deceiving.

Here is an initialization suggestion, it is for a List as you described in your question, but can easily be modified to correspond to any `IEnumerable` , also, it can be done in a different method being executed prior to `Main` (again, by the looks of your code it seems unlikely) :

```
private List<GameObject> queue; // assuming it's private, doesn't really matter either way.

static void Main()
{
    queue = new List<GameObject>(); // the missing line
    GameObject obj1 = new GameObject();
    GameManager manager1 = new GameManager();
    obj1.name = "First";
    manager1.Add(obj1);
    manager1.Process();
}


public void Add(GameObject gameObject)
{
    gameObject.initialize = true;
    queue.Add(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: How do you know queue is a List could be a Dictionary or anothing?

Comment: Have you considered that the queue is in fact a System.Collections.Generics.Queue<>?

Comment: It's in the OP description - "queue is a list", either way , I will add clarification since it doesn't really matter what type of IEnumerable it is, all need initialization :)

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Should have looked more into lists.

Comment: So he did sorry @Ron B.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize Queue list first

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code.

I assume you are using Visual Studio, if so then do this:

1. Go to the Debug menu.
2. Click on the the Exceptions... choice.

The following dialog should appear:

[image]

Note: the Common Language Runtime Exceptions checkbox is checked.

Upon clicking OK, now when you debug your code anytime an exception is thrown by your code or the .NET Framework, the debugger will halt on the line that threw the exception. This makes finding where something is "breaking" much easier.

Comment: This would only really help for exceptions which are caught/handled/swallowed. For an unhandled exception like the one the OP described, the debugger is going to break anyway.

Comment: @MattDavey - No, this will break as soon as an exception is thrown; not when it bubbles all the way up the chain.

Comment: I understand that, but for unhandled exceptions you're not going to see any difference in behaviour by doing this. The debugger is still going to break on the line that threw the exception regardless.